# Raster statistic

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, qgis-modeler, rasterstats

i'm try to use QGIS processing modeler but I've a problem.
I need to use the Mean value and the standard deviation in raster calculator algorithm. I've calculated it in raster statistics, how can I do now to use this values in raster calculator formula?

[image]

Comment: Create a raster with that values in each pixel of two bands. Then make the algebra between rasters.